# Rust Shadowing memory management

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

```
fn main() {
  let x = 5;
  let x = x + 1;
  let x = x * 2;
  println!("The value of x is: {}", x);
}
```

When your code calls a function the function’s local variables get pushed onto the stack. When the function is over, those values get popped off the stack.

During shadowing what happens to the variable x that we declared first? Do we overwrite the memory location of x or we create a new x at another location in the stack?

Comment: In the general case the other `x` doesn't even have to have the same type, e.g. you can write `let x = format!("{}", x)`, so there is certainly no requirement for the memory location to be reused. What happens is exactly the same as  if the variables were named `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc. - the location is _semantically_ left alone, but the optimizer is free to optimize away some (or all) of the locations, or place them in registers, and so on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do we overwrite the memory location of x or we create a new x at another location?

Semantically, a new memory location is created and "x" now points to that location. Depending on the optimisations being applied, the compiler *could* reuse the memory location instead. Or not even allocate a memory location at all, really e.g. here with optimisations enabled it'll constant fold everything and directly print the constant `12`.

Comment: Yeah. But I just want to know how rust memory optimisations work. Does the old memory location reallocated or destroyed?

Comment: The question doesn't really make any sense? The memory is part of the stackframe so it gets allocated by moving the stack pointer on function entry, and deallocated by moving it back on stack exit. And since this is not a `Drop` type there is no observable behaviour, LLVM's optimisation passes are unconsrtrained. If it were a Drop type, then by default the memory would be kept alive until scope exit as that's basically the guarantee rust provides for "named" (non-temporary) local values.

Comment: @MadduSwaroop With today's optimizers, local variables in plain-text code do not map directly to memory locations on the stack. Compilers can and will reuse memory locations, keep things in registers, and consolidate operations if the visible results of the program are the same.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo for what it's worth, in my experience modern compilers don't seem to bother much optimising stackframes temporally (AKA reusing dead stack locations). Aggressive inlining and DCE and register optimisation sure, but create a bunch of locals over one another and [you'll see them creeping forward in the frame](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=b9143b6fce4189bdd1ea7b03867294fc).